# Create Linux executable without options from Linux executable with specific options

Tags: bash, executable

I have an executable in Linux, lets call it `run_program` that takes some options, e.g. `-i 7`. I want to test this executable using testing software that also comes as an executable, lets call it `run_test`. However, this testing software can only take the executable without options. So calling `./run_test -s { run_program -i 7 }` does not work (I am not even sure that the way I parenthesized is correct but  I was told that passing options with `run_program` is not going to work anyway).

The executables were compiled using g++ if that makes a difference.

My idea is to create a new binary that does what a call to `run_program -i 7` would otherwise do, using bash. Can anyone more knowlegabele than me in bash tell me how that might work?

I am also open for different solutions!

Comment: please update the question to use actual examples of what you're trying to do; right now you're referencing `exec` and `test` which are builtins in `bash` (`test` is also a binary), so using the names `exec` and `test`, in the context of a `bash` environment, is just compounding the confusion

Comment: This question is missing too many details to give a reasonable answer. What does "create a new binary...using bash" mean? Does your executable HAVE to take arguments for the test? Do you own either the executable or the test software, and if so why not fix them directly?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @markp-fuso I was not aware of that. I hope the confusion is lifted

Comment: still confused ... does `run_test` *actually run* the executable named `run_program`? and if so, how can `run_test` do that without knowing the run time parameters required by `run_program`?

Comment: @markp-fuso: I think `run_test` just assumes that there are no run-time parameters requires. That seems like suboptimal design for a tester, but that's not the responsibility of OP.

Comment: from what you've stated ... *`I am not even sure that the way I parenthesized is correct but I was told that passing options with run_program is not going to work anyway)`* ... it sounds like *someone* knows how `run_test` works so ... have you asked that individual for additional details on how to use `run_test`?

Comment: I think what @M.NejatAydin said is what I am looking for. Have not tested it yet but that coincides with my idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wrapper script with the content

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /path/to/run_program -i 7
```

Make the script file executable, and run

```
./run_test -s ./wrapper_script
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the (so far) confusing/limited input I'm leaning towards a function, eg:

```
my_test() {
    run_test -s $1          # effectively ignore anything past the 1st argument
}

# or as a one-liner:

my_test() { run_test -s $1; }
```

Taking for a test drive:

```
my_test run_program -i 7    # should result in: run_test -s run_program
```